# Mysql Query with multiple tables for datamining

Tags: mysql

I need help to do a query. What I am trying to find out is 
Which crime is most likely to happen in each month?

I have a main table which has IDs to connect to other tables. It has the crimeID, dateID, offenceID, boroughID and crimeCount.

I have a table for date, offence and borough aswell, which link to this table. 
I want to get the offence from the offence table, i want the months from the month table and in my main table it is seperated by borough so i want the offence to be added up in each borough and month. Let me know what other information you need.
[Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFlpB.png)

[offence table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bANDD.png) from offence table i want actualOffence column

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've piece together what you're looking for. Sounds like you want to group by the report by crimeID and the month it occurred. You will need to join these tables together and group by month, crimeID. Then sort by the count of the occurrence month.

Ex. (loosely based off your description).

```
SELECT MONTH(B.date),crimeID,C.actualOffence,COUNT(*) FROM main_table A
JOIN date_table B ON A.dateID = B.ID
JOIN offence_table C ON A.crimeID = C.ID
GROUP BY MONTH(B.date),crimeID,C.actualOffence
ORDER BY MONTH(B.date) ASC,COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: This assuming you replace the actual IDs descriptor with the actual fields from your tables.